# Open file in java isn't working properly

Tags: java, xml, file

My code:

```
JFileChooser opChooser=new JFileChooser();
            FileNameExtensionFilter filter=new FileNameExtensionFilter("XML File", "xml");
            opChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
            int returnVal=opChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
            File chosenFile=opChooser.getSelectedFile();

            try
            {
                if (returnVal==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                {
                    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(chosenFile));
                    currentDirectory="";
                    textPane.setText("");
                    textPaneError.setText("");
                    currentDirectory=chosenFile.getAbsolutePath();

                    String data = "";
                    while ((br.readLine())!=null)
                    {
                        data += br.readLine();
                    }
                    doc.insertString(0, data, null);
                    br.close();
                }
            }
            catch (IOException | BadLocationException ex)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "ERROR!!!");
            }
        }
```

My xml file that i want open in my app:

```
<note>
<to>Tove</to>
<from>Jani</from>
<heading>Reminder</heading>
<body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>
</note>
```

Result:

```
<from>Jani</from><body>Don't forget me this weekend!</body>null
```

I would be grateful if someone could explain me why the result is not like a xml file? Where are the first two line, and why the last string inserted is null?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `br.readLine()` in the while condition without setting it to a value

try this:

```
String data = "";
String temp = "";
while ((temp = br.readLine()) != null)
{
   data += temp;
}
```

Comment: You should use a `StringBuilder` for `data` instead of `String`.